# Unable to decrypt using data using AES, which is encrypted in C# using RijndaelManaged

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to decrypt data which is encrypted in C# using RijndaelManaged
Here is the .net code

C# Encryption Code:-

```
private string Encrypt(string textToEncrypt)
        {
            string key = "BHMACLDBApp";
            RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
            rijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            rijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            rijndaelCipher.KeySize = 0x80;
            rijndaelCipher.BlockSize = 0x80;
            byte[] pwdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
            byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0x10];
            int len = pwdBytes.Length;
            if (len > keyBytes.Length)
            {
                len = keyBytes.Length;
            }
            Array.Copy(pwdBytes, keyBytes, len);
            rijndaelCipher.Key = keyBytes;
            rijndaelCipher.IV = keyBytes;
            ICryptoTransform transform = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor();
            byte[] plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToEncrypt);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(transform.TransformFinalBlock(plainText, 0, plainText.Length));
        }
```

C# Decryption code:-

```
  private  string Decrypt(string textToDecrypt)
        {
            string key = "BHMACLDBApp";
            RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
            rijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            rijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            rijndaelCipher.KeySize = 0x80;
            rijndaelCipher.BlockSize = 0x80;
            byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(textToDecrypt);
            byte[] pwdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
            byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0x10];
            int len = pwdBytes.Length;
            if (len > keyBytes.Length)
            {
                len = keyBytes.Length;
            }
            Array.Copy(pwdBytes, keyBytes, len);
            rijndaelCipher.Key = keyBytes;
            rijndaelCipher.IV = keyBytes;
            byte[] plainText = rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText);
        }
```

I have tried these codes at my end. But no success.

```
- (NSData *)decrypt:(NSString *)key withData:(NSData*)data{
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    BOOL patchNeeded = ([key length] > kCCKeySizeAES256);
    if (patchNeeded) {
        key = [key substringToIndex:kCCKeySizeAES256]; // Ensure that the key isn't longer than what's needed (kCCKeySizeAES256)
    }

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if (patchNeeded) {
        keyPtr[0] = '\0';  // Previous iOS version than iOS7 set the first char to '\0' if the key was longer than kCCKeySizeAES256
    }

    NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [data bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key withData:(NSData*)data{
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionECBMode,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [data bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesDecrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

- (NSData *) DecryptAES: (NSString *) key andData:(NSData*)data
{
    char  keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1];
    bzero( keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr) );

    [key getCString: keyPtr maxLength: sizeof(keyPtr) encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;

    NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];

    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer_decrypt = malloc(bufferSize);
    const unsigned char iv[] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};

    CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt( kCCDecrypt , kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionECBMode,
                                     keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                     iv,
                                     [data bytes], [data length],
                                     buffer_decrypt, bufferSize,
                                     &numBytesEncrypted );

    if( result == kCCSuccess )
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer_decrypt length:numBytesEncrypted];

    return nil;
}
```

I have even tried this but no success

```
- (NSData *)doCipher:(NSData *)dataIn
                  iv:(NSData *)iv
                 key:(NSData *)symmetricKey
             context:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt
{
    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus   = kCCSuccess;
    size_t          cryptBytes = 0;    // Number of bytes moved to buffer.
    NSMutableData  *dataOut    = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:dataIn.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];

    ccStatus = CCCrypt( encryptOrDecrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                       kCCOptionECBMode,
                       symmetricKey.bytes,
                       kCCKeySizeAES128,
                       iv.bytes,
                       dataIn.bytes,
                       dataIn.length,
                       dataOut.mutableBytes,
                       dataOut.length,
                       &cryptBytes);

    if (ccStatus != kCCSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"CCCrypt status: %d", ccStatus);
    }

    dataOut.length = cryptBytes;

    return dataOut;
}
```

If I keep option ECB then I get data, but when I convert it to string I got null.

```
NSString *base64S=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64S  options:0];
                    NSString *decodedString64 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"Final Decoded %@", decodedString64);
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am stuck in this from last 4 days. But haven't got any working solution.

Comment: You're using an IV of all zeroes in the Objective-C code, but using the key as the IV in .NET, they need to be the same for decryption to be successful. I also note mentions of AES256 in the Objective-C, but you're using AES128 in .NET, again, these need to be the same.

Comment: Note that often decryption will work, as any byte array can always be decrypted. The only thing that could fail decryption is if the input is different from the number of blocks, or if the padding is incorrect. If decryption runs without error then that does not mean that the key, IV, mode or ciphertext is correct.

Comment: @Iridium you checked one method only, in that it will use AES128 if key is 16 bytes. For IV I have provided it with key bytes as well. But No success.

Comment: You need to supply _all_ the same parameters and options, it is that simple. Do some hex data dumps on both for all inputs and compare. Use the same options, you can't mix CBC with ECB, etc. You are even specifying kCCAlgorithmAES128 with kCCKeySizeAES256, really examine your code.

Comment: @Zaph I think you checked one code of mine, I have tried different ways.. Though I got the answer to my question myself.. Thanks for your time dear

Comment: @Sabby you should post the answer if you have got the solution, even if you yourself have found the solution, rather than keeping the question unanswered, so that it can help others.

Comment: Sure @Bonnie, I will do that.

Answer (score -2):

```
NSData *toencrypt = [strString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSData *pass = [[kUserDefaults objectForKey:@"aLoginToken"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSData *iv = [[kUserDefaults objectForKey:@"aLoginToken"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSData *bytes = [self dataFromHexString:strRework];
```

//[[kUserDefaults objectForKey:@"aLoginToken"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]

```
CCCryptorStatus status = kCCSuccess;

NSData * encrypted = [[NSData alloc] init];
encrypted = [toencrypt dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm:kCCAlgorithmAES128 key:pass initializationVector:iv options:kCCOptionPKCS7Padding error:&status];
NSString * strChiperText = [encrypted base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn ];
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please elaborate your answer by explaining your source code.